# Convert List of integers to a single number in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, integer

Convert a list to a number from type int

```
a = [ 21, 12 ,54, 8 , 2 ,1]
```

to

```
b = 211254821
```

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), a)`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [ 21, 12 ,54, 8 , 2 ,1]
>>> b = int(''.join(map(str, a)))
>>> print b
211254821
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=[2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b="".join(map(str,a))
>>> b
'23456'
>>> c=int(b)
>>> c
23456
>>>
```

There can be a smaller way to directly convert but at present im new in python so dont know.